# Compare select parts of 2 Strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
0: {Id: 1, type: dog, changeNo: '0123-123-A1', …}
1: {Id: 2, type: cat, changeNo: '0123-123-F2', …}
2: {Id: 3, type: bus, changeNo: '0456-154-E5', …}
n: {Id: n, type: n, changeNo: 'n', …}
length: n
```

So I'm currently learning JS and react and am trying to check an object array in the form above for the same changeNo up to the second '-'. So I'd like to know if, and how many '0123-123' there are. I figured I'd iterate over the array checking for whether either string is a subset of the other, however that would lead me into errors with almost everything as it checks the adjacent Lettering as well.

```
let multi: number;
    for (let i=0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        for (let j=1; j <= data.length; j++) {
            while (data[i].changeNo.indexOf(data[j].changeNo) >-1) {
                multi ++;
            }
        }
    } 
return multi-1;
```

Is there a way to easily compare the strings in a for while loop based on the first few elements. Or maybe a way to stop comparing once the second '-' is reached?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this can be done with an if check if(obj.countNo.startsWith('0123-123')) then count++

Comment: So the changeNo value can be whatever, it doesn't have to be 0123-123

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = [
    {Id: 1, type: 'dog', changeNo: '0123-123-A1',},
    {Id: 2, type: 'cat', changeNo: '0123-123-F2',},
    {Id: 3, type: 'bus', changeNo: '0456-154-E5',},
    {Id: 4, type: 'n', changeNo: 'n',}
];

//getting all matches:
console.log(input.filter(item => item.changeNo.split('-').slice(0, 2).join('-') === '0123-123'));

//getting the first two matches only
let found = 0;
let index = 0;
let output = [];

while ((found <= 2) && (index < input.length)) {
    if (input[index].changeNo.split('-').splice(0, 2).join('-') === '0123-123') {
        output.push(input[index]);
        found++;
    }
    index++;
}

console.log(output);
```

Explanation:

- the `.changeNo.split('-').slice(0, 2).join('-')` part takes `changeNo`, creates an array from it from all sections between dashes, gets the first two elements and glues them together into a string, resulting in `0123-123`, for example
- the first solution uses `.filter()` to find all matches based on your criteria
- the second solution will stop when two matches were found